# Use of conjunctions

Tags: conjunctions

Can conjunctions be added after certain adverbs, as in the following sentence :

- We see them sporting in the sea, where no one should be found yet each one must be keen as they play hide-and-seek.

or does the adverb "where" makes the conjunction "yet" seem to appear in discontinuity ?

Answer (score 2):

> *In the sea,* [*where no one should be found yet each one must be keen as*
>   *they play hide-and-seek*].

The bracketed element is a supplementary (non-defining) relative clause in which the preposition "where" has the PP "in the sea" as antecedent.

Supplementary relatives are not modifiers but separate units of information, non-constituents, that have a semantic 'anchor'. Here the anchor is the PP "in the sea".

Note that "yet" is not a conjunction, but a connective adverb with a concessive meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Following the principles described by John Ross in his famous dissertation [Infinite Syntax](https://books.google.com/books/about/Infinite_Syntax.html?id=43tiAAAAMAAJ), an adverb can be moved to the beginning of coordinated clauses only if it was in both clauses before being moved. In your example,

> ... in the sea, where no one should be found yet each one must be keen as they play hide-and-seek.

"where" represents the "there" which occurs in each of the two coordinated clauses:

> no one should be found there
>
> each one must be keen as they play hide-and-seek there